# Nginx Ingress Controller - AKS Azure Load Balancer cannot be reached with the hostname

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I have a `private` AKS cluster and I am using nginx ingress controller. So far, I have done the following.

1. Install nginx ingress controller

```
NAMESPACE=jananath-test

helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx  \
--repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx  --namespace $NAMESPACE --create-namespace
```

2. Create a simple deployment with ingress resource

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
  labels:
    app: nginx-test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-test-image
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-test
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  # annotations:
  #   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2  
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: jananath.test
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Above will result in creating an Azure Load Balancer **automatically**.

Once deployed, I can also successfully see the EXTERNAL-IP as below (a fake IP to hide my actual IP is given below)

```
# kubectl get ing

NAME                  CLASS   HOSTS             ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
minimal-ingress       nginx   jananath.test   20.6.21.123      80      6m58s
```

3. Since I don't have a domain yet, I added `jananath.test` to my `/etc/hosts` entry as below:

```
20.6.21.123 jananath.test
```

But the problem is when I try to access the deployment with `http://jananath.test` / `https://jananath.test` (probably https wouldn't work as I haven't specified any certificates.

But I can't reach, browser keeps spinning as you know it.

Can someone help me to troubleshoot what is going on?

Ingress controller logs are seem to be fine too as I don't see any errors.

Is this because I am using a private cluster? or the Load Balancer created by the ingress resides in one of the Resource Groups created by the AKS cluster (When deploying) and somehow doesn't have access from the internet?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: does `curl http://jananath.test` works inside the cluster?

Comment: @Sibtain I am using a jumphost to connect to the cluster. Even from the jumphost it doesn't work

Comment: you need to add the `/etc/hosts` entry in the jump host or where ever you are trying to access the URL `http://jananath.test`, provided that it can connect to the LB IP address

Comment: @Sibtain i have already added that as well. But still not working. Are there anything I should look into from the Load Balancer side?

Comment: not really, but you might want to take a step back and try to curl to the LB IP directly either from within the cluster or on jump host

Comment: @Sibtain to the port 80 right?

Comment: Yes, if 80 is the port where your nginx ingress controller is deployed

Comment: @Sibtain I tried `telnet <LB-IP>:80` and still it is not reachable. Are there any NSg's assigned to LB? I can't see them.

Comment: what is the output you get when trying `curl http://20.6.21.123 -H "Host: jananath.test" -v`?`

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I am getting nothing at all: `*   Trying 20.6.21.123:80...* TCP_NODELAY set`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to repro this in both **public AKS** cluster and **private AKS** cluster. I am successfully able to browse the application using the **nginx-ingress** service in both the clusters.

Below are the steps given to repro it in **private AKS** cluster.

**Step 1:** Create a private AKS cluster by enabling the private cluster option.
[image]

**Step 2**: Create **Jump Box** to connect to the private cluster.
I have created **ubuntu 20.04** VM and installed **kubectl** tool.

[image]

```
$ az login
$ az aks get-credentials --resource-group rgvjy --name aks-vjy
```

**Step 3:** Steup **nginx-ingress controller** on the AKS cluster.
I have deployed ingress controller on the cluster by using **helm** and it creates a **load balancer service** automatically.

```
$ NAMESPACE=ingress-basic
$ helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
$ helm repo update
$ helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --create-namespace --namespace $NAMESPACE --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz
```

[image]

Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli) for more information on creating ingress controller.

**Step 4:** I have deployed the nginx application in the namespace where ingress is deployed.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-deploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-deploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-deploy
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: test-deploy
```

[image]

```
$ kubectl apply -f test-deploy.yaml -n ingress-basic
```

**Step 5:** Create an Ingress route to the application.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test-deploy(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-deploy
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-deploy
            port:
              number: 80
```

[image]

```
$ kubectl get ingress -n ingress-basic
NAME                 CLASS   HOSTS   ADDRESS       PORTS   AGE
test-nginx-ingress   nginx   *       20.81.x.xxx   80      110s
```

**Step 6:** Add ingress load balancer IP address in the **/etc/hosts** file in the **jump box** to check connectivity using the **DNS name** resolution.
[image]

[image]

```
$ curl http://test-nginx-ingress/test-deploy
```

**Note: The DNS name won't work from the internet as we are referring it in the internal hosts file**

**Step 7:** Browse the ingress loadbalancer IP/[route-name] in google to check ingress route.
[image]

**Note:  In this repro I have placed application deployments and nginx-ingress deployment in the same namespace.**

Comment: @Jananath Banuka, did it work ?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact answer to your question but I encountered the same issue and found a workaround so posting here hoping it'd help someone.

My setup was exactly similar to yours only it was a public cluster. And I too was not able to access the application through the browser however it worked through a curl command with http.

I also tried out a different ingress controller option (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing?tabs=default%2Cdeploy-app-default) which too resulted in the same issue.

Somehow it felt not implementing SSL is the culprit here so I went ahead and implemented SSL for the initial setup (self managed nginx ingress controller). Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls?tabs=azure-cli for more information.

And as soon as SSL was implemented, the application was accessible via the browser.

However I'm still not sure the reason for not being able to access the same with http. As per my knowledge it is certainly possible to expose an application over HTTP without SSL using an Ingress controller. SSL is not a strict requirement, and you should be able to access your application via HTTP.